# What's the implicit difference between time (t) and delta time (Δt) in a ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was doing a problem set then I stumbled upon this question:

> Early one morning it starts to snow. At 7 AM a snowplow sets off to clear the road. By 8 AM, it has gone 2 miles. It takes an additional 2 hours for the plow to go another 2 miles. Let t = 0 when it begins to snow, let x denote the distance traveled by the plow at time t. Assuming the snowplow clears snow at a constant rate in cubic meters/hour. Find the DE modeling the value of x.

The solution provided:

> Let **k<sub>1</sub>** be the rate (in height/hour) of snowfall and **k<sub>2</sub>** be the rate of snow clearance. The height of snow is **k<sub>1</sub>t**, therefore **Δx(k<sub>1</sub>)t ≈ (k<sub>2</sub>)Δt**. So **(Δx/Δt) ≈ k/t** where **k = k<sub>1</sub>/k<sub>2</sub>**. This is then **dx/dt = k/t** where **k** is a constant.

What I still don't understand is why the solution used **t** instead of **Δt** in **Δx(k<sub>1</sub>)t**. From what I understand, we use **t** only if **k<sub>1</sub>** is not a constant; yet, it is stated above that **k** is a constant.

Helpful answers to correct my understanding would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $\Delta t$ is the time since the plowing started
- $\Delta x$ is distance the snowplough cleared
- $t$ is the time since the snowfall started.

I hope this helps.